# PolarPlot shows nothing for a simple function

Tags: plotting, bugs, trigonometry

**Bug introduced in 8.0.4 or earlier and persists through 12.0.0. Fixed in 12.1.0. Affects only Windows.**

I just tried to plot `Tan[t]^4` as a polar plot and got... nothing.

```
PolarPlot[Tan[t]^2, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

Works:

[image]

```
PolarPlot[Tan[t]^4, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

Doesn't work:

[image]

Changing the `4` to a `4.` to enforce numerical results doesn't change anything.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug? In case it matters:

```
$Version
```

> ```
> "11.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 28, 2016)"
> ```

Comment: `PolarPlot[Tan[t]^4, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]` works in 11.1 for macOS for me. Are you able to upgrade?

Comment: @user6014 I'm using my 11.1 licence on another machine, so not until 11.2 or 12.0 is out. I guess I'll just generate my plots on that other machine then.

Comment: Actually, I tested this on my Windows 10 machine running 11.1 and it failed as well. Perhaps report this to support. It also works in the Wolfram Cloud (Linux based), so this seems to be a Windows only issue.

Comment: In that case, I'd appreciate a workaround in the answers.

Comment: Does `ParametricPlot[Tan[t]^4 AngleVector[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]` work?

Comment: @J.M. Unfortunately not.

Comment: It's not working  on `"11.0.1 for Microsoft Windows (32-bit) (September 21, 2016)"` too.

Comment: Can you try adding `PlotRange -> All` to your original plot?

Comment: It seems to be an issue with how the Windows Mathematica FrontEnd renders it, because `Export["test.pdf", PolarPlot[Tan[t]^4, {t, 0, 4 Pi}]]` shows the lines...

Comment: @J.M. [I tried that.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYkcP.png) In that instance it seems to attempt to plot the line (I see a narrow blue line about the axis), but the PlotRange is 1.5x10^13, so it is less than useful. Playing around with PlotRange didn't get me very far.

Comment: @user, well, `Cases[Normal[PolarPlot[Tan[t]^4, {t, 0, 2 π}]], Line[l_] :> l, ∞][[1]]` shows that a line is getting plotted, but a look at the values of the coordinates tells me that the automatic `PlotRange` determined is way off the actual extent of the curve.

Comment: `PolarPlot[Tan[t]^3, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 50] /. x_Real :> Clip[x, {-500, 500}]` an extremely stupid solution, but possibly works sometimes, at least here...... some extra optimization of `Clip`'s value may make the process more automated.

Comment: I've contacted Wolfram support, will edit the question when I back from them.

Comment: Displays the curve on `"11.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (July 28, 2016)"` and `"10.3.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (October 9, 2015)"`.

Comment: `PolarPlot[Tan[t]^4, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 100,  MaxRecursion -> 1]`

Comment: Mathematica 8.0.4 on Win7x64. This works: `PolarPlot[Tan[t]^(2 + 4 10^(-15)), {t, 0, 2 Pi}] `.  This does not work: `PolarPlot[Tan[t]^(2 + 5 10^(-15)), {t, 0, 2 Pi}] `.

Comment: Wolfram support have confirmed that this is a bug, so I've added in the usual header. They've also suggested `MaxRecursion -> 1` as a workaround.

Comment: Bug reproduced in MMA 11.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was originally confirmed by Wolfram Support to be a bug and has now been fixed in 12.1.0:

```
PolarPlot[Tan[t]^4, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

This also fixes the following snippets from the comments:

```
ParametricPlot[Tan[t]^4 AngleVector[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

```
PolarPlot[Tan[t]^(2 + 5 10^(-15)), {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]